# How can I populate HKU registry entries through GPO?

Tags: windows, group-policy, internet-explorer, windows-registry

I need to disable two different TLS settings in IE Control Panel (TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1). I need this to be applied only once, and to have the user/an admin be able to go in and change the settings without them being applied again.  We mostly have Windows 8.1, a few Windows 10.

I figured I could do this through GPO preferences in the registry section and using the 'apply once' checkbox in the common options; however, I need to add this key to the HKU/{User-SID}/ section of the registry. The users I will be applying this to already have profiles on the computers in question, and I cannot delete them.

Is there any easy way to do this through GPO? I could probably script it, but I would rather just use GPO.

Thanks

Comment: `HKEY_USERS\{user-sid}` is also known as `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and is the default for registry entries created using user (rather than computer) group policy preferences.